# Почему тормозит TreeView?

Tags: c#

При большом количестве веток дерева, у меня начинает тормозить TreeView, а точнее, обычная операция присвоения имени ветки:

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Text = "hello!";
```

Тестирую на разных компьютерах. Эта операция может занимать от 100 мс до 1 сек при 35 тыс веток. Если больше, то время пропорционально увеличивается. Можно ли решить эту проблему?

Comment: Предположу, что проблема может быть в отрисовке визуального дерева. Это довольно ресурсоёмкое действо, поэтому используется много элементов в TreeView или различных листах, то можно воспользоваться виртуализацией (вот даже на стеке можно посмотреть): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549209/wpf-treeview-virtualization

Comment: WinFroms или WPF?

Comment: WinForms .......

Answer (score 0):

Это известная проблема всех UI элементов. Собственно снижение производительности с увеличением числа элементов, в первую очередь связано с тем, что отрисовка и обработка другой логики всех UI элементов выполняется в одном потоке (по этой же причине не рекомендуется в логике контролов лазить за данными в БД или выполнять тяжелые вычисления). При этом надо учитывать, что одна из самых тяжелых операций, при нормальном использовании контролов, - отрисовка, выполняется даже для тех элементов, которые в данный момент не отображаются (находятся за границами родительского контрола при скроле или, как в случае с TreeView, "свернуты" под "плюсик"). Таким образом, не важно как вы разместите N тысяч UI элементов, в видимой области формы, спрячете за скролом или TreeView - "тормозить" будет абсолютно одинаково - пропорционально их количеству.

Решение тоже известное - виртуализация отображения.

Применительно к TreeView, это можно реализовать например так:

1. Дерево элементов храним в отдельном объекте.
2. При первичном отображении TreeView заполняем только видимый уровень элементов.
3. На событие [TreeView.BeforeExpand](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforeexpand?view=netframework-4.7.2) вешаем обработчик, который будет заполнять дочерние элементы узла до их отображения в видимой области.
4. На событие [TreeView.AfterCollapse](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercollapse?view=netframework-4.7.2) вешаем обработчик, который будет удалять дочерние элементы узла после их скрытия из видимой области.

Это конечно увеличит время выполнения разворачивания и сворачивания узлов, но заметно прибавит производительности при большом количестве элементов. Исключительный случай, в котором данный прием не сработает - все узлы на одном уровне. Но это скорее вырожденный случай и потребуется менять способ их отображения.